# I do not understand the mechanism of "Transform weapon in transform" in Unity C# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

How does the code "Transform weapon in transform" allow variant weapon to enumerate all the child instances (such as carbine, shotgun) of weapons parent instance?

[hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm5FF.png)

code:

```
private void SetWeaponActive()
    {
        int weaponIndex = 0;

        foreach (Transform weapon in transform) 
        {
            if (weaponIndex == currentWeapon)
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            weaponIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is "Transform" a base class inherited by other weapons (gun, ...) ?

Comment: @Arcord this is Unity and [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) is a built-in component attached to any `GameObject` and `transform` an accessory property implemented in `Component` ;)

Answer (score 1):

As to **how/why** can it do that.

If you look into the [`Transform` Source Code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs) you will see it implements the [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) interface doing

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Transform.Enumerator(this);
    }

    private class Enumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        Transform outer;
        int currentIndex = -1;

        internal Enumerator(Transform outer)
        {
            this.outer = outer;
        }

        //*undocumented*
        public object Current
        {
            get { return outer.GetChild(currentIndex); }
        }

        //*undocumented*
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            int childCount = outer.childCount;
            return ++currentIndex < childCount;
        }

        //*undocumented*
        public void Reset() { currentIndex = -1; }
    }
```

So basically it is just a handy shortcut for doing

```
for(var i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    var weapon = transform.GetChild(i);

    ...
}
```

---

Then either you would have to store the actual **reference** and do

```
private Transform currentWeapon;

...

foreach(Transform weapon in transform)
{
    weapon.gameObject.SetActive(weapon == currentWeapon);
}
```

or

```
private Transform currentWeapon;

...

for(var i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    var weapon = transform.GetChild(i);

    weapon.gameObject.SetActive(weapon == currentWeapon);
}
```

Or if you store the index rather do

```
private int currentIndex;

...

for(var i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    var weapon = transform.GetChild(i);

    weapon.gameObject.SetActive(i == currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The parent transform has 3 children. You can iterate over them and deactivate all that are not "current weapon". Sounds simple.
But comparing the int `weaponIndex` to a Transform will not work.

You should use a traditional for loop, as it gives you the index to compare.

```
int currentWeapon = 0 // the weapon you want to activate
for(int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
{
    if (i == currentWeapon)
    {
        transform.getChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.getChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```